# Why combining calls to AppendLine and Length of StringBuilder produce strange results with WinForm's TextBox？

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, newline, stringbuilder

I was practicing windows form.

The book recently taught `StringBuilder`, so I typed the book's example.

The example code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp32
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder str1;
            str1 = new StringBuilder(5);
            str1.Append("1234");
            textBox1.AppendText("Capacity=" + str1.Capacity.ToString() + "\r\n");
            str1.Append("5768");
            textBox1.AppendText("str1=" + str1.ToString() + "\r\n");
            textBox1.AppendText("Length=" + str1.Length.ToString() + "\r\n");

            str1.Length = 15;
            textBox1.AppendText("Capacity=" + str1.Capacity.ToString() + "\r\n");
            textBox1.AppendText("Length=" + str1.Length.ToString() + "\r\n");
            textBox1.AppendText("str1=" + str1.ToString() + "\r\n");

            str1.Clear();
            str1.Append("123");
            textBox1.AppendText("str1=" + str1.ToString() + "\r\n");

        }

       
    }
}
```

When it shows on the FormsApp, it looks like this:

[image]

`str1=123` didn't on the new line,

so I added `"\r\n"` in front of `"str1=" + str1.ToString() + "\r\n"`.

After doing that, the FormsApp shows like this:

[image]

My question is :

I already has `"\r\n"` in previous `AppendText`.

After using Clear() and Append() method,

why `str1=123` isn't automatically on the new line?

...................................................

After changing Append() to AppendLine(),

The FormsApp shows like this:

[image]

I only changed `str1.Append("123");` to `str1.AppendLine("123"+"\r\n")` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try the same code in a Console Application, with `textBox1.AppendText` replaced with `Console.Write`? I can't reproduce the problem in a Console Application, and I don't have a Windows machine, so I think it might be the text box doing something funny.

Comment: Generally it is off-topic on SO to ask why designers of a library decided to pick a particular behavior... (Also in this case it is likely a good old tradition - maybe Pascal one - to use WriteLine to write with new line and all corresponding methods that add/don't add new line named similarly)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It isn't off-topic at all to ask why the line break at the end of `"str1=" + str1.ToString() + "\r\n"` isn't working. I am not convinced that most of the commenters have actually read the code.

Comment: As mjwills has answered, your action of setting the Length of the stringbuilder to 15 cause the SB to put ASCII NUL characters onto its end. Windows controls, being C++ based beasts, will stop processing any text after the first ascii NUL, because they think they've reached the end of the string.(eg putting `abc<NUL>def` into a textbox makes it to show `abc` only). **You do not need to micromanage the Length of a stringbuilder; don't do it** An SB will expand automatically. About the only time you want to set the length is to 0 (clear) or maybe minus it to trim separator chars added in a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect most of the commenters have not read the code in detail, and thus haven't realised that all of your appending to the textbox *already* include a line break.

So - why are they not showing?

You are running into a variant of [Null character deleting rest of output in TextBox and RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346286/null-character-deleting-rest-of-output-in-textbox-and-richtextbox) . Basically, if you insert text into a textbox then anything after a `NULL` character gets stripped.

**But where did the `NULL` character come from?**

Well, it came from the `StringBuilder` (when you explicitly set the `Length` to greater than the current length). As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.length?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> If the specified length is less than the current length, the current
> StringBuilder object is truncated to the specified length. If the
> specified length is greater than the current length, the end of the
> string value of the current StringBuilder object is padded with the
> Unicode NULL character (U+0000).

Now, since you inserted the line break *after* the `NULL` character then effectively the line break was lost on your second call to

```
textBox1.AppendText("str1=" + str1.ToString() + "\r\n");
```

The easiest solution is to comment out:

```
str1.Length = 15;
```

to avoid the `NULL` characters getting there in the first place.